# Why thread sync is not happening while using pthread_cond_wait and pthread_cond_signal, failing 30 times in 100 cycles

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads, thread-synchronization

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
using namespace std;
pthread_mutex_t mutexVar = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_mutex_t mutexSync = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t condVar = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;


void startReceiving()
{
    while(1)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutexVar);
        cout<<"lock mutex and waiting for cond_signal"<<endl;
        pthread_cond_wait(&condVar, &mutexVar);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutexVar);
        
        cout<<"Received cond_signal"<<endl;
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        {
            cout<<i<<" ";
        }
        cout<<endl;       
    }
}

void func1()
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutexSync);
    cout<<"calling cond_signal func1"<<endl;
    pthread_cond_signal(&condVar);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutexSync);
}

void func2()
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutexSync);
    cout<<"calling cond_signal func2"<<endl;
    pthread_cond_signal(&condVar);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutexSync);
}

void func3()
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutexSync);
    cout<<"calling cond_signal func3"<<endl;
    pthread_cond_signal(&condVar);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutexSync);
}
int main()
{
    thread t1(startReceiving);
    cout<<"started startReceiving and waiting"<<endl;
    sleep(2);
    thread t2(func1);
    thread t3(func2);
    thread t4(func3);
    
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    t3.join();
    t4.join();

    return 0;
}
```

What i observed is, startReceiving() requires more time to execute compare to other functions, so when we send cond_signal from func1() and by the time startReceiving() completes it's execution, func2() will also send the cond_signal and cond_wait is missing that 2nd signal because startReceiving() is not yet ready to receive the cond_signal. Is my understanding right??

One way i tried to improve this is by adding sleep() inside every func call after cond_signal, but not sure this will work or not. Because facing the issue 3 times in 10 cycles. Because of this issue, i am missing the data in startReceiving()

So how to improve this code with respect to sync or anything else i am missing here.

Comment: That's why you have to write `while(something) {pthread_cond_wait(&condVar, &mutexVar);}` and all the tutorials should tell you that. You use these to wait for a condition to be true, which is why they're called *condition variables*. You don't just use wait/signal by themselves.

Comment: What do you mean by "improve" the code? It's toy code, isn't it? It has no shared state, so there's really nothing to improve.

Comment: Currently, `startReceiving` call `pthread_cond_wait` even when there is nothing for it to wait for. This code cannot be improved until it has something to wait for.